# How to pin posts in django?

Tags: python, django

So i want to know how to pin posts in django. When i click on check, and click create post, it should pin the post to the top. And newer posts will just appear bottom, without interfering with the pinned post. The pin system should also be able to pin multiple posts. So if i pin another post, both posts should stay at the top. The other **not** pinned posts should just appear below.

`models.py`

```py
class AskSection(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_pin = models.BooleanField()
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User,  related_name='likes', blank=True) 
    is_marked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_posted']
        verbose_name_plural = "Ask Section"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

`forms.py`

```py
class AskSectionCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    is_pin = forms.BooleanField(label="pin ask post", required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = AskSection
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'is_pin')

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            }),
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            }),
        }
```

`views.py`

```py
@login_required
def create_ask_post(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AskSectionCreateForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data.get('title')
            description = form.cleaned_data.get('description')
            is_pin = form.cleaned_data.get('is_pin')

            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.title = title
            obj.description = description
            obj.is_pin = is_pin
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()

            messages.success(request, f'You have posted {title} successfully')
            return redirect('/details_ask/' + str(title) + '/')
        else:
            form = AskSectionCreateForm()
    else:
        form = AskSectionCreateForm()
    
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, "editor/create_ask_post.html", context)
```

`html file`

```html
{% for question in all_questions %}
   <!-- random HTML not important code --> <!-- code is related to just the styling of posts and just model fields -->
{% endfor %}
```

so please let me know how to do this. The HTML file isn't really important. It just contains the card, and model fields.

Thanks!

Comment: when you want to do a lot with ordering I would suggest to add something like a `rank` field (integer) to your model. set the rank really high (could also combine with your is_pin Bool). in your views where you get "all_questions" add a `.order_by("rank", "-is_pin")` sort them in the right order. the minus infront of `is_pin` is set so True will come first.

Comment: thanks, this is kind of helpful. But could you show me a code example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you don't really need another field in your model you could just work with your DateTimeField but as commented before I would add a `rank = models.Integerfield(default=0)` to the `AskSection` model. (Don't forget to migrate)

you have a views.py file with a function where you set the context for your html (not the one you showed in your answer but the other one where you define `all_questions`). here you can set an order for all_questions like so `all_questions = AskSection.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by("rank", "-is_pin")`. Your code might look a little different now I dont know if you filter by user I just assumed that...

When a User adds a new question you increase your the rank on the new question so you always have a clean order. Whenever a user "Pins" a question you take highest rank and add a number + set the `Boolean` to `True`.

An alternative way would be working with the Datefield `date_posted` like so
`all_questions = AskSection.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by("date_posted", "-is_pin")`. in that case the date would act as a "rank". saves you a migration but its not as flexible as a Integerfield.

Comment: both of them don't work. They just put the pinned posts at the very bottom. But i want the at the top. And no new posts should go above them. Could you do that? Thanks!

Comment: Try to change the order and the remove or add the minus. I am not quite sure what the right way is.  I guess this works for your case  `.order_by("-is_pin", "date_posted")`

Comment: thank you! it works. I just had to do a little bit more of filtering, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: sorry. But i have another question. Does using the `date_posted` work for any timezone? I mean to say does it pin that post in any timezone? Thanks!

Comment: Your server works in a ttimezone (check settings.py) and it basically does not care where your users are from and what time it is on their watch. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/timezones/ check the first sentence.

Comment: so, it will be pinned correctly in any timezone right?

Comment: hi, can you also answer this post? Thanks!                                                                                                                                        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66750610/how-to-assign-model-fields-to-a-custom-variable-in-the-view-and-use-it-in-conte